# Как сократить jquery код

Tags: javascript, jquery

В общем есть такой вот Jquery код

```
//Добавление нового пункта
$('.SumoSelect').on('click', '.newSumo', function(){
    newopt = $(this).parents(".SumoSelect").find('.search-txt').val();
    //Добавляем новый параметр
    $(this).parents(".SumoSelect").find("select")[0].sumo.add(newopt);
    //Убираем все выбранные
    $(this).parents(".SumoSelect").find("select")[0].sumo.unSelectAll();
    //Выбираем новую опцию
    $(this).parents(".SumoSelect").find("select")[0].sumo.selectItem(newopt);
    //Перезагружаем блок
    $(this).parents(".SumoSelect").find("select")[0].sumo.reload();
});
```

Как видно я постоянно обращаюсь к одному и тому же месту через $(this).parents(".SumoSelect").find("select").

Вопрос. Как правильно это сократить?﻿

Comment: `var el = $(this).parents(".SumoSelect").find("select");`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Сам сейчас занимаюсь изучением Wordpress, вот неплохая статья все очень грамотно описано [https://habrahabr.ru/post/228523/](https://habrahabr.ru/post/228523/)

Answer (score 3):

Сохраните повторяющуюся часть в переменную:

```
//Добавление нового пункта
$('.SumoSelect').on('click', '.newSumo', function(){
    newopt = $(this).parents(".SumoSelect").find('.search-txt').val();

    var sumo = $(this).parents(".SumoSelect").find("select")[0].sumo;

    //Добавляем новый параметр
    sumo.add(newopt);
    //Убираем все выбранные
    sumo.unSelectAll();
    //Выбираем новую опцию
    sumo.selectItem(newopt);
    //Перезагружаем блок
    sumo.reload();
});
```

Comment: Благодарю. Работает